# Modify range() during for loop

Tags: python

can I modify `range()` during for loop?

```
for i in range(10):
    if something:
        pass
        # change range
    print(i)
```

An example:
Let method `something` be `i == 5` and the body will decrease range by one.

```
Expected output:
0
1
2
3
4
5
5
6
7
8
9
```

I have a little more complex `range()` like `range(0, len(data), 1024)`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want such control of your loop, it's better to use `while` rather than `for`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the number of iterations in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905606/changing-the-number-of-iterations-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: I also advice you to use `while` in this case

Comment: Why would you do that? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot modify the generator used in the `for` loop during the iteration process. Instead, you could refactor your code using a `while` loop. For example, if your range is `range(start, stop, step)` (using the notation similar to that used in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)), you can write the loop as follows:

```
i = start
while i < stop:
    # do stuff
    i += step
```

This allows you to modify `i` however you'd like inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
i = 0

while i <= 5:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
i = i - 1
while i <= 10:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
```

As others have said, it is probably best to use a `while` loop in this scenario and manually increase your value every time the loop is performed, rather than using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of modify it within the `for` loop using `break` keyword.

```
start_val  = 0
stop_val = 10
for i in range(start_val ,stop_val):
    if i==5:
        start_val = 5
        print(i)
        for i in range(start_val ,stop_val):
            print(i)
        break
    print(i)
```

This gives expected output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
5
6
7
8
9
```